# Default scheme and 3 slashes in URL after using urlparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I need to provide a default scheme to URL if it doesn't contain it.
I managed to make it with the code below:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
print(urlparse('google.com', 'https').geturl())
# 'https:///google.com'
```

But for some reason, it returns a URL with three slashes. What is the meaning behind them? is it still a valid URL?

Comment: Why do you use `urlparse`? There is nothing to parse in `'google.com'`.

Comment: I need to provide a default scheme to URL if it doesn't contain it.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give a more realistic example? Here you could just directly write `'https://google.com'` to get the desired result.

Comment: The reason why you get three slashes is that `geturl` combines `<scheme>://<netloc>/<path>` with empty `<netloc>` and `google.com` as `<path>`.

Comment: `'google.com'` isn't a valid URL: garbage in garbage out